# How can I make my class decorator only run on the outermost class in an inheritance chain?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, decorator

I'm using [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) decorators to validate data classes that involve data coming from outside of my application at runtime.  I want my classes to validate themselves on instantiation.  I've written a class decorator to easily add this functionality to classes.

```
import * as t from 'class-validator';

interface Class {
  new(...args: any[]): {};
}

export function autoValidate<T extends Class>(target: T) {
  return class extends target {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);

      const errors = t.validateSync(this);

      if (errors.length > 0) {
        throw errors;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

The problem with this class decorator is that when inheritance comes into play where a class and its ancestor are both decorated with this decorator.

```
@autoValidate
class Parent {
  @t.IsNumber()
  readonly age: number;

  @t.IsString()
  readonly name: string;

  constructor(age: number, name: string) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

@autoValidate
class Child extends Parent {
  @t.IsBoolean()
  readonly happy: boolean;

  constructor(age: number, name: string, happy: boolean) {
    super(age, name);

    this.happy = happy;
  }
}
```

When `Child` is instantiated, the validator will throw an error in `Parent`'s constructor's decorator when `super` is called in `Child`'s constructor/decorator because `happy` is `undefined`.

How can I alter my decorator such that it will only run its validation code if `this` is an instance of `target` but not a descendant of `target`?

Comment: `if (this.constructor === target)`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think you are close, but `this.constructor` will be the wrapped class and will never equal `target`, so instead the decorator needs to save the wrapped class so `this.constructor` can be compared to it.  Want to write an answer with this corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution based on Patrick Roberts's idea, with additional protection against defining a subclass and forgetting `@autoValidate` (which would otherwise lead to no validation at all):

```
import * as t from 'class-validator';

interface Class {
  new(...args: any[]): {};
}

const lastClassWithValidation = Symbol();
export function autoValidate<T extends Class>(target: T) {
  return class extends target {
    static [lastClassWithValidation] = target;
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);

      if ((<any>this.constructor)[lastClassWithValidation] === target) {
        const errors = t.validateSync(this);

        if (errors.length > 0) {
          throw errors;
        }  
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Seems to me it would be less messy to do `if (Object.getPrototypeOf(<any>this.constructor) === target)`, that way you don't pollute the static properties of the class with implementation details.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That way doesn't provide the protection against subclasses without `@autoValidate`.  If that protection isn't desired, sure.  If it is, the natural thing would be to use a symbol.  I'm not convinced that having a string-named static property is a big deal, but it's easy enough to use a symbol, so I updated the answer.

Comment: Nice touch using a symbol to avoid the member being picked up when serializing the class to JSON.